# Select all rows contains same value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all `package_id` that contain `product_id 2`.
In this case, `package_id 1,3,5` has `product_id 2`

```
Table: product_package

package_id    package_name    product_id
---------------------------------------------
1               Gold                1,2,3
2               Platinum            4,5,12
3               Diamond             2,11,5
4               Titanium            3,5
5               Basic               2
```

I tried:

```
SELECT
                   *
                FROM
                    product_package
                    WHERE product_id IN(2)
```

It is outputting `package_id 3 and 5` only. How do I output this properly?
`product_id`    structure is `varchar(256)`. Should I change the structure or add Foreign keys?

Comment: *Should I change the structure* - yes. Storing delimted values in a single column violates first-normal form.

Answer (score 1):

We always recommend not to stored delimited columns see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

But you can use `FIND_IN_SET` but this is always slow

```
SELECT
                   *
                FROM
                    product_package
                    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,product_id)
```

| package_id | package_name | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gold | 1,2,3 |
| 3 | Diamond | 2,11,5 |
| 5 | Basic | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UzojazAy)

Answer (score 1):

First, let me explain what is happening in your query.

You have `WHERE product_id IN(2)`, but product_id is a misnomer and should rather be product_id**s**, because it is multiple IDs unfortunately stored in a string. `IN` is made to look up a value in a list. Your list, however, only consists of one element, so you can just as well use the equality operator: `WHERE product_id = 2`.

What you have is `WHERE string = number`, so the DBMS has to convert one of the values in order to compare the two. It converts the string to a number (so '2' matches 2 and '002' matches 2, too, as it should). But your strings are not numbers. The DBMS should raise an error on '1,2,3'  for instance, because '1,2,3'  is not a number. MySQL, however, has a design flaw here and still converts the string, regardless. It just takes as many characters from the left as they still represent a number. '1' does, but then the comma is not considered numerical (yes, MySQL cannot deal with a thousand separator when convertings strings to numbers implicitly). So converting '1,2,3' to a number results in 1. Equally, '2,11,5' results in 2, so rather surprisingly '2,11,5' = 2 in MySQL. This is why you are getting that row.

You ask "Should I change the structure", and the answer to this is yes. So far your table doesn't comply with the first normal form and should thus not exist in a relational database. You'll want two tables instead forming the 1:n relation:

Table: package

| package_id | package_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Gold |
| 2 | Platinum |
| 3 | Diamond |
| 4 | Titanium |
| 5 | Basic |

Table: product_package

| package_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 |

You ask "or add Foreign keys?", and the answer is *and* add foreign keys. So with the changed structure you want product_package(product_id) to reference product(product_id) and product_package(package_id) to reference package(package_id).

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding that you should not be storing multiple values in a single field, you can use `LIKE` operator to achieve what you are looking for. I'm going with assumptions:

- all values are delimited with commas
- all values are integers
- there are no whitespaces (or any other characters besides integers and commas)

```
select * from product_package
where product_id like '2,%'
   or product_id like '%,2,%'
   or product_id like '%,2'
   or product_id like '2'
```

Alternatively, you can use `REGEXP` operator:

```
select * from product_package
where product_id regexp '^2$|^2,.+|.+,2,.+|.+,2'
```

References:

- [MySQL LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)
- [MySQL REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)